# Generic return type of interface not checked correctly

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

Here's the code. It should be checked, but it isn't, as of TS 5.2.2.

```js
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(sth: T) {}
}

interface Test {
    bar(): Foo<{ a: number }>;
}

class CTest implements Test {
    bar() {
        return new Foo({ b: 1 });
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6w8AdhAC4BOArsKfOQBRkAWAXNCgJRYC+2v2ASyKkApuQBmYYCPYiyWXPnGJ6HNgmSZoYNkUoBbAEZjo3NAG4+2bKEgwAwijmloA-QAcQI-SOEwn8jj40MrwqgrBweQipJTkRNBEIgDucCpahmwAjKYclsG8vEA) for the above code.

Comment: what's the error message, and what's your want?

Comment: @xgqfrms I want the compiler to show error, but it goes just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Foo<T>` class instance type doesn't actually *use* the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`.  An instance of `Foo<T>` is [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) identical to the empty object type `{}`, and thus `Foo<{a: number}>` and `Foo<{b: number}>` are mutually assignable.  Unused generic type parameters are discouraged for this reason.  See [the relevant TypeScript FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).

---

You might object that `sth` is of type `T` and therefore `Foo<T>` does use `T`, but note that this is only the type of the *constructor* of `Foo<T>`.  That is, `typeof Foo` (the class constructor) depends on `T`, but the type `Foo<T>` it constructs (the instance type) does not.  It's essentially like writing

```
declare const Foo: new <T> (sth: T) => Foo<T>;
interface Foo<T> {};
```

so while the type of the `const` named `Foo` is a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) with some dependence on its generic type parameter, the type `Foo<T>` has no such dependence.

---

Anyway if you want to prevent this from happening you should ensure that an instance of `Foo<T>` has some structural dependence on `T`.  Usually this is in the form of a property of that type.  In this case you might want to actually use the constructor argument as the value of that property:

```
class Foo<T> {
    sth: T;
    constructor(sth: T) { this.sth = sth }
}
```

And now you get the error you were expecting:

```
interface Test {
    foo(): Foo<{ a: number }>;
}

class CTest implements Test {
    foo() { // error! 
    //     Type 'Foo<{ b: number; }>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<{ a: number; }>'.
        return new Foo({ b: 1 });
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAUQI4FcCWA3FAb2GBTJRxABcoAnAMyVQDEB7VgHgBUA+IlAL4BuUuQAmURABswtVIlYgYVFG1YAuFCCgB3FNz4AKZQAtNXAJQoAvHzUGR5CtTqNkKLrBXEnT+u0MLTXtCFDBNECwIACM6QR5HcgESJ2kwGBgUAGFPZQoIOCkoaGpM3O9RXxR-VkCiSqryOSosWhAtXVUA0OjNAEZBC0Sq5Kdk4HG0jK7OXnqnU3NhlAUlKlosRCpWWmMqMw8rUP2cGAA6UxsUS+TxyhoGJg8vefIawOD2DlDwrSjY2jxESTGTTHIvHAFIolKhlF4+N4BI4oAD0KJQdFoOwAhCgGmjfFwAJ5wVAAchCKF6fxidCE8TJFEyIFYKnSMBwAHNwNEiihtvySeTKb9IrTaPSBDwyWcGk5mq12to9GpDD1+oNlrdgEA)